# Selenium - When browser Driver version will get released

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, microsoft-edge, geckodriver, selenium-edgedriver

When can we get the selenium driver versions after the browser upgrade.

For Chrome driver I got info(https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) - Before a new major version of Chrome goes to Beta, a matching version of ChromeDriver will be released.

For other browsers(Firefox,Edge,IE..) when can we get the updated driver versions when the browser is upgraded.

I'm not able to find clear information other than chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For the IE browser, you can download the IE driver server from the link below.

[Download Internet Explorer Driver Server](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

For the MS Edge legacy browser prior to **version 18**, you can download the web driver from the link below.

[Download Microsoft Edge Legacy web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

If you want to download the web driver for the MS Edge legacy browser >= **version 18**, you can refer steps below.

Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge version 18 is a Windows Feature on Demand.

To install run the following in an elevated command prompt:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

For the MS Edge (Chromium) browser, You can download the latest version of the web driver from the link below.

[Download MS Edge (Chromium) web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

You can refer to the link below to view the full version directory from starting to the latest version of web driver for MS Edge (Chromium) browser.

[Full version directory](https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/)